# Possible to install PHP 5.2.17 on a new CentOS 6.4 system?

Tags: centos, yum, php

I'm trying to set up CentOS 6.4 (Linux 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64) with a specific version of PHP (5.2.17) as it is required by an app I'm trying to install.

I've downloaded the PHP version and dependencies. This version of PHP requires a downgraded php-common which then required an earlier libcurl.

On trying to downgrade libcurl to the required version yum fails as it seems yum itself depends on this. Which makes sense really.

The list of packages that would be affected (and erased) is huge. So it seems that this version of PHP is a bridge too far as libcurl is just too embedded.

**Should I start again with an earlier version of CentOS?  I'm new with Linux but might it be that PHP is el5 but CentOs is el6?**

PHP package: php-5.2.17-1.el5.art.x86_64.rpm

libcurl: curl-7.15.5-17.el5_9.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing the PHP Application requirements? Does it state that it does not work on 5.3?

Comment: Also, EL4, EL5, EL6 means it is based on "Enterprise Linux" AKA Redhat EL5 or Redhat EL6.

Comment: I could be confusing things, I'm not an expert with Linux. However that PHP package does request a libcurl which it seems I just can't get without wiping and starting again. If I try to, it tries to downgrade yum as well as a lot of firmware and drivers. Pretty drastic for just a PHP install, I think we'll go with CentOS 5.x to see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to downgrade to an older version of a package using the previous versions of RPMs. Here you're trying to downgrade using the CentOS 5 packages on CentOS 6. This is a bad idea.

You have a couple of options.

1. Get the source RPM (SRPM) file that was used to built `php-5.2.17-1.el5.art.x86_64.rpm`, and build it yourself on CentOS 6, using:

   ```
   $ rpmbuild --rebuild <srpm>
   ```
2. Setup multiple versions of PHP using these howtos:

   - [Intall multiple version of php on one server](http://linuxplayer.org/2011/05/intall-multiple-version-of-php-on-one-server)
   - [How To Use Multiple PHP Versions (PHP-FPM & FastCGI) With ISPConfig 3 (CentOS 6.3)](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-use-multiple-php-versions-php-fpm-and-fastcgi-with-ispconfig-3-centos-6.3).
3. Download PHP and compile and install it yourself to a directory such as `/opt`, then use the PHP package manager PEAR to install any needed PHP modules.

   - [Installing PHP packages with PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.installing.php)